# Mapping a sphere to a tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry

If I have an approximation of a sphere, how do I map the vertices of the sphere to form a (regular) tetrahedron?

My current approach maps all vertices of the sphere to just one of the four vertices of a tetrahedron. However I want them to be evenly spaced, if that is possible.

I would be thankful for any approach or solution.

EDIT: Changed "rectangular" to regular.

Comment: I don't know what 'vertices of a sphere' are. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I guess your vertices are a finite set of points that happen to be on the sphere, right ? Are those already evenly spaced on the sphere ?

Comment: oh yeah also, how are the coordinates of the points encoded ? Eulidean ? Spheric ?

Comment: What is a "rectangular" tetrahedron?

Comment: Yes, i have a finite set of points. I use them to render the sphere in my program. The coordinates are given as cartesian coordinates. so (x,y,z).

Comment: Sorry i meant "regular".

Answer (score 1):

Assume the sphere is centered in 0, radius 1.

Let $x_1,y_1,z_1, ... x_4, y_4, z_4$ be the vertices of the dual tetrahedron : $(\pm 1, 0, -1/\sqrt{2}),\,\,\,\,\, (0, \pm 1, 1/\sqrt{2}).$.
Let $(x,y,z)$ be a point of the spheres. Compute the dot products $x_ix+y_iy+z_iz$ for i=1..4. Find the $i$ for which it is positive and maximal. This tells us which face of the tetrahedron we should look at. Suppose for now that $i=1$.

Then we want to project on the face orthogonal to $x_1,y_1,z_1$. 
Let $\alpha$ the factor we want to multiply $(x,y,z)$ with. We want $\alpha(x,y,z)$ to belong to the plane orthogonal to $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and passing through it. This is equivalent to "$\alpha(x,y,z) - (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ orthogonal to $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$", equivalent to (by taking dot product) $\alpha(xx_1 + yy_1 +zz_1) = (x_1^2 + y_1^2 +z_1^2)$.So $\alpha = \frac {x_1^2 + y_1^2 +z_1^2}{xx_1 + yy_1 +zz_1}$.

Same if $i\neq 1$.

Comment: I edited because i wasn't projecting correctly in a first version.

Comment: edited again since i had forgot to remove the bad part in a first edit.

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be to put the center of your "sphere" and of your tetrahedron in the point $(0,0,0)$, and then for every "vertice of the spehere" $v_n$  find the intersection of the line segment $[0,v_n)$ with the tetrahedron. Call this intersection $t_n$, and thus your map becomes $v_n\mapsto t_n$.

The term "evenly spaced" requires some clarifications, both involving the nature of your sphere approximation, shape of tetrahedron, and what are the desired properties of this map.

Comment: Maybe evenly spaced wasn't the right term. I have the vertices of a my "sphere". I want to transform the sphere to a tetrahedron by just changing the distance of the vertex to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Can you map a cube inside a sphere?  Now choose a vertex, and the 3 non-adjacent vertices, and you have a regualar tetrahedron.

e.g.

$(\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},\frac {\sqrt 3}{3})\\
(-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},\frac {\sqrt 3}{3})\\
(\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3})\\
(-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},\frac {\sqrt 3}{3},-\frac {\sqrt 3}{3})$

Answer (score 0):

Following is a construct which sends every point other than origin to
the surface of a tetrahedron containing origin in its interior.
The distribution is not uniform, directions near the edges will be more
spaced out than directions near center of the tetrahedron faces.

---

Given any tetrahedron $T$ containing origin $O$ in its interior.
Let $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ be the its vertices ordered so that following
4 triples of vertices
$$
p_1p_2p_3,\quad 
p_1p_3p_4,\quad
p_1p_4p_2\quad\text{ and }\quad
p_2p_4p_3$$
are oriented counterclockwisely on its boundary $\partial T$.
Let the corresponding
faces be $F_4,F_2, F_3$ and $F_1$. i.e. $F_i$ is the face opposite to vertex $p_i$.

Consider face $F_4$, its outward pointing normal is pointing along the direction

$$v_4 = (p_2-p_1)\times(p_3-p_1) = p_1 \times p_2 + p_2\times p_3 + p_3 \times p_1$$
For any point $p \in \mathbb{R}^3$, it is coplanar with $F_4$ when and only when
$$v_4 \cdot p = \Delta_4 \iff \frac{v_4}{\Delta_4} \cdot p = 1
\quad\text{ where }\quad\Delta_4 = p_1 \cdot v_4 = p_1 \cdot (p_2 \times p_3) > 0
$$
Define $v_1, \Delta_1$ for face $F_1$, $v_2, \Delta_2$ for face $F_2$ and $v_3, \Delta_3$ for face $F_3$ in a similar manner.

Now consider the mapping

$$\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ O \} \ni p
\quad\mapsto\quad
\varphi(p) =
\frac{p}{
\max\left\{
\frac{v_1\cdot p}{\Delta_1},
\frac{v_2\cdot p}{\Delta_2},
\frac{v_3\cdot p}{\Delta_3},
\frac{v_4\cdot p}{\Delta_4}
\right\}}
\in \mathbb{R}^3
$$
Notice $T$ contains $O$ in its interior.
For any $p$ other than $O$, there is always an $i$ such that $v_i \cdot p > 0$.
This means the denominator in the definition of $\varphi(p)$ is positive.
As a result, $\varphi(p)$ lies on the ray from $O$ to $p$.

It is clear for some $i$, the maximum of $\frac{v_i}{\Delta_i}\cdot p$ is reached.
For that $i$, $\frac{v_i}{\Delta_i}\cdot \varphi(p) = 1$ and hence $\varphi(p)$ lies on the plane containing $F_i$. It is also clear for all $j$,
$\frac{v_j}{\Delta_j}\cdot \varphi(p) \le 1$, this means $\varphi(p)$ actually
belongs to some face $F_i \subset \partial T$.

Based on this, we can conclude the map $\varphi$ 
sends every point $p$ other than $O$ to the intersection of the ray $Op$ with the surface of tetrahedron $T$.

As a concrete example, consider the case $T$ is the regular tetrahedron
with vertices at $$p_1 = (1,1,1),\quad p_2 = (1,-1,-1),\quad p_3 = (-1,1,-1)\quad\text{ and }\quad p_4 = (-1,-1,1)$$

One can works out
$$v_1 = (-4,-4,-4),\quad v_2 = (-4,4,4),\quad v_3 = (4,-4,4)\quad\text{ and }\quad v_4 = (4,4,-4)$$
and $\Delta_1 = \Delta_2 = \Delta_3 = \Delta_4 = 4$. The map $\;\phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ O \} \to \partial T\;$ becomes

$$(x,y,z)\quad\mapsto\quad \frac{1}{\max(-x-y-z,-x+y+z,x-y+z,x+y-z)} (x,y,z)$$